# How to use PrototypeJS .wrap() on a $$('selector') array in a single statement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototypejs

Coming from a jQuery background onto a project using PrototypeJS.

```
$('someId');
```

In PrototypeJS [will return the element with the given id](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/).

```
$$('ul.someClass li');
```

will return the the elements matching the CSS selector, but in [a document-ordered array](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/).

How can I run [`wrap()`](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Element/prototype/wrap/) on the elements in the console, on a single line, since the `iterator` argument on [`each()`](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Enumerable/prototype/each/) needs to be a function that only takes a collection element and an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Enumerable#invoke method to apply your method and arguments to the collection. Just tried the following, and it worked on the first try:

```
$$('p').invoke('wrap', 'div', {className: 'foo'});
```